# Changing the style of words when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a menu that doesn't point to a new page, it changes content on the same page.

I Tried CSS but cant get it to work for this. Is it possible in pure CSS?

The script I wrote works by getting the page title, but there is no page title.

**Concept**

The First ITEM "OVERVIEW" should be highlighted bold when the page is first opened. Then on click another link the "OVERVIEW" drops the bold and the new link becomes bold and so on.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="bblock1" style="height:100%;">
<div class="container">
<div class="bodymainMaxS">
    <div class='tabbed_content'>
        <div class='tabs'>
            <div class='moving_bg'>&nbsp;</div>
            <span class='tab_item'>OVERVIEW</span>
            <span class='tab_item'>THE SCIENCE</span>
            <span class='tab_item'>ORDER</span>
            <span class='tab_item'>REPLACEMENT FILTERS</span>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.tabbed_content {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
}

.tabs {
    position: relative;
    width:70%;
    float:left;}

.tabs .moving_bg {
    background-color:;
    background-image:url(/images/arrow_down_blue.png);
    position: absolute;
    width: 600px;
    z-index: 7;
    left: 0;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
    background-position: left bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

.tabs {}

.tab_item {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    color: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 8;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'SourceSansPro-SemiBold';
    font-size: 15px;

    background-image: url('images/circleA.png');
    border-left: 1px solid #333;
    padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;  
}
.tab_item:hover {
    color: #fff;

}
.tab_item:visited {
    color: #fff;

}
```

**Fiddle**:

https://jsfiddle.net/y2c2hdvx/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery you just need to write few lines (see fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bLqf1rkw/3/) ):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".tab_item").on("click", function() {
    $(".tab_item").removeClass("bold");
    $(this).addClass("bold");
  });
});
```

with css:

```
.tab_item.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

(you could also change font-weight instead of toggling the class)

Comment: no need to toggle, as you are removing them. just use `addClass`.

Comment: Hi, ok i typed that too. it broke my code when i used that. but it does work just doesnt work with the other script i have running on the element. Please see new fiddle for the code that it brakes. https://jsfiddle.net/y2c2hdvx/7/

Answer (score 0):

try it :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".tab_item").on("click",function(){

        $(".tab_item").removeClass("active");

        $(this).addClass("active");

    })

})
```

Final code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .tabbed_content {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
}

.tabs {
    position: relative;
 width:70%;
 float:left;}

.tabs .moving_bg {
    background-color:;
    background-image:url(/images/arrow_down_blue.png);
    position: absolute;
    width: 800px;
    z-index: 7;
    left: 0;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
    background-position: left bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 margin: 0 auto;

}


.tab_item {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    color: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 8;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
 font-family: 'SourceSansPro-SemiBold';
 font-size: 15px;
 background-image: url('images/circleA.png');
 border-left: 1px solid #333;
 padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align:center; 
}

.tab_item:visited {
 color: #fff;

}
 .tab_item:hover {
        color: #111;
    }    

        .active {
             font-weight:bolder;
        }

    </style>
</head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="bblock1" style="height:100%;">
<div class="container">
<div class="bodymainMaxS">
 <div class='tabbed_content'>
     <div class='tabs'>
         <div class='moving_bg'>&nbsp;</div>
         <span class='tab_item active'>OVERVIEW</span>
         <span class='tab_item'>THE SCIENCE</span>
         <span class='tab_item'>ORDER</span>
     </div>
 </div>
</div>
            </div></div>
        
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $(".tab_item").on("click",function(){
        
        $(".tab_item").removeClass("active");
        
        $(this).addClass("active");
        
    })
    
})

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes but once they are clicked they stay "visited". i have tried.

Comment: @alwayslearning  ,    you want after click item get `color : #fff ` or `color : #111` ?

Comment: on page open "overview" is bold, click another item then overview drops bold, and new item becomes bold

Comment: @alwayslearning , i update code. when page load item of "overview" is bold and whenclick  another item , "overview" drop bold and new item get bold.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<title></title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">


div.nav_container ul li{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 30px;
  display: inline;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bebold{
  font-weight: bold;
}

.nobold{
  font-weight: normal;
}



</style>

<body>

<div class="nav_container">
  <ul>
   <li>OVERVIEW</li>
   <li>THE SCIENCE</li>
   <li>ORDER</li>
   <li>REPLACEMENT FILTERS</li>

  </ul>
</div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

$("div.nav_container ul li").click(function(){

   $("li").removeClass("bebold");
   $(this).addClass("bebold");
});


</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Toggling text style on click is possible with pure css. Unfortunately I can't think of a way to remove styling on *Overview* when the others are clicked. Lots of ways to do it all with JS of course.

Here's the pure css approach for toggling styles using `:target`

```css
.tabbed_content {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
}
.tabs {
  position: relative;
  width:70%;
  float:left;
}
.tabs .moving_bg {
  background-color: none;
  background-image:url(/images/arrow_down_blue.png);
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  z-index: 7;
  left: 0;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  background-position: left bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.tabs {}
.tab-item {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  color: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 8;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'SourceSansPro-SemiBold';
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-image: url('images/circleA.png');
  border-left: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align:center;  
}
.tab-item:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
#ti1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}
.tab-item:visited {
  font-weight: normal!important;
  color: #CCC;
}
#ti1:target, #ti2:target, #ti3:target, #ti4:target   {
  font-weight: bold!important;
  color: black!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="bblock1" style="height:100%;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="bodymainMaxS">
      <div class="tabbed_content">
        <div class="tabs">
          <div class="moving_bg">&nbsp;</div>
          <a class="tab-item" href="#ti1">
            <div id="ti1">OVERVIEW</div>
          </a>
          <a class="tab-item" href="#ti2">
            <div id="ti2">THE SCIENCE</div>
          </a>
          <a class="tab-item" href="#ti3">
            <div id="ti3">ORDER</div>
          </a>
          <a class="tab-item" href="#ti4">
            <div id="ti4">REPLACEMENT FILTERS</div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/e5kykj8e/

Here's an old but recently updated click-to-slide-open accordion menu using pure css :target for those who find their way here from google.

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/cfLqbvgm/3/